# Alternatives to GeoWebCache?

Tags: caching, geospatial, wms

Does anyone know alternatives to GeoWebCache (GWC)?

There's TileCache, but it seems to be "dead" in terms of no more development taking place. In addition to that i can't figure out how to cache a protected WMS with TIleCache (basic auth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TileCache isn't dead: it works great and has an active mailing list.  (I'd call it "mature".)

To use TileCache with a protected WMS, look at these two references on the mailing list:

- [patch](http://openlayers.org/pipermail/tilecache/2007-June/000243.html) allowing the TileCache client to make authenticated requests
- [discussion](http://openlayers.org/pipermail/tilecache/2008-January/000694.html) of how to authenticate requests to a TileCache server (if you have content you want to protect)

Comment: Thank you!

Hmmmm, i got stuck with GWC anyhow... =)